# jQuery Mobile slow performance on android tablets

Tags: android, performance, jquery-mobile

We are running a jquery mobile website/webapplication. We have noticed that on the ipad everything runs very smooth, but on our Galaxy tab 10.1 the performance is very bad. The pages are nothing special, but when we click something it does not do anything for like 2-4 seconds.  That results in very bad user experience. I'm pretty sure it's not the hardware, because the specifications are good, but there seems to be a delay on click events. Is this browser behavior or something else?

We are testing on Dolhpin Mini (browser), but the problem also exists in the default browser and in chrome.

Does anybody encountered a similar problem or can you point me in the right direction to fix this? I know The question may sound vague, but we

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer, I made it few hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986390/1848600

These methods are verified on android phones, I believe same should translate to android tablets. Your best bet is fast click implementation. This will reduce click lag.

Unfortunately there is no perfect solution for the android platform, specially for 2.X version.